# My PS3 IP address changed again?

Tags: ps3

Alright  so 11 days ago when i got back from work after 9pm I saw that my ps3 IP address the same one I had for two years had changed. I was able to go online but when I did  a connection test it failed and gave me an error code. So I power cycled my modem and router and my IP address went back to normal and connection test went fine.

Today when I had gotten home and turned my ps3 on around 8pm, it happened again so naturally I power cycled again and it went back to normal again.

However now I'm worried, the first time this happened I check some of my other devices and their ip's were the same, just my ps3 changed. So now I'm wandering if something is wrong with my ps3 or router.

The most recent changes that happend to my router was that back in July I did changed my security from WPA to WPA 2, plus my router EA4500 firmware updated around that time too. In early August I changed my Wireless channel from 1 to 6 since most people in my Neighborhood were on channels 1 and 11.

So yeah is this a router or a ps3 issue. The only other problem I would get from time to time is were my upnp became Not availiable so I had to power cycle then as well.

....................................
Here is a link in case anyone wants to take a look at my Playstaion forum post

http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-General/My-PS3-IP-address-changed-again/td-p/44439826

Comment: Please post your full question here, not just a link to some forum.

Comment: Fine I'll edit it then.

Comment: I read the other thread, basically quit worrying.  Whats probably happening is some other device is fighting for the same internal IP and PS just says OK I'll use another one instead.

Comment: I guess I will. Its just that this has never happened to me before these two times, and it just gave me a scare since my other devices "seemed" to be unaffected but not my PS3. But I guess if its just a minor issue then I will stop worrying.

Comment: I saw that my router has a dhcp reservation option so I put my PS3 and some of my other devices in that option.